# What does output of Chef "knife node show" command mean?

Tags: chef

With reference to the following command:

`knife node show hostname`

I see output for:

```
Run List:
Roles:
Recipes:
```

What does `Recipes:` mean in this context? I presume it means that these are the recipes executed by the Chef node?

The reason for my question is as follows.

Assume a cookbook:recipe of `cookbook_a:default`.

If I search for cookbooks:

`knife search node "cookbooks:cookbook_a"`

I get a long list of nodes which are pulling `cookbook_a` through Berks dependencies.

If I execute the following more specific search for recipes:

`knife search node "recipes:cookbook_a\:\:*"`

I get a much shorter list of nodes.

When I query `knife node show hostname` for any of these nodes, I can see `cookbook_a:default` listed under `Recipes` in the output. But I only see this on these nodes, not on the the longer list of nodes from the previous search command.

My understanding is that if a cookbook is pulled by a node, it will automatically execute the default recipe.

So if the cookbook is being pulled by lots of nodes, why isn't the default recipe listed as being executed on all these nodes?